# Atualizar dados do formulário com React hook form e Yup

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, yup

Eu tenho um campo do formulário

```
        <Controller
      control={control}
      name="name"
      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
        <>
          <TextInput
            className={`text-base p-2 border rounded-lg border-gray-400 text-gray-500 mb-8 ${alertName && "border-red-500 mb-0"}`}
            placeholder="Nome de usuário"
            maxLength={50}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
          {errors.name && <Text className="mt-2 mb-4 text-red-500">{errors.name.message}</Text>}
        </>
      )}
    />

E quero que já esteja com um valor name já preenchido que vem de

const { userData, signOut, userUpdate } = useAuth()
const { sub, name, avatarUrl } = userData as User
```

mas quando o usuário tenta editar o campo atualiza e não permite edição, como posso fazer para que o TextInput mostre o valor de name, mas permita editar esse valor?

Answer (score -2):

Conseguir resolver, era só definir um valor padrão. Fiz dessa forma:

```
        <Controller
      control={control}
      name="newName"
      defaultValue={name}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
        <>
          <TextInput
            className={`text-base p-2 border rounded-lg border-gray-400 text-gray-500 mb-8 ${errors.newName && "border-red-500 mb-0"}`}
            placeholder="Nome de usuário"
            maxLength={50}
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
          {errors.newName && <Text className="mt-2 mb-4 text-red-500">{errors.newName.message}</Text>}
        </>
      )}
    />
```

defaultValue={name} recebe o nome padrão e permite o usuário editar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).